# How to get the estimated row count for paginated queries CockroachDB

Tags: sql, database, cockroachdb

How would I see how many rows were scanned in my query? Im using `LIMIT` so i know how many rows are going to be returned but i'd like to see how many rows were scanned.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `EXPLAIN` to analyze the query.

Depending on how you've set up your table and your query the estimated scanned row count can vary a lot.

There is a good example in the CockroachDB docs about the benefits of using keyset pagination and demonstrating the performance using `EXPLAIN`
See: https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/stable/pagination.html#keyset-pagination